# How to display main Window before launching ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window

I have an application where, upon launching a my `MainWindow`, I need to perform some actions that involves a `DateTime` object. Sometimes I can read the `DateTime` from some data, but otherwise I need to ask for user input.

For the latter, I have designed a new simple `MyDatePicker` which contains a `Calendar` control.

My issue is that the `MyDatePicker` dialog is shown before the `MainWindow` appears. Naturally, this happens as the dialog is shown from the `MainWindow` constructor. I would like the `MainWindow` to appear before the `MyDatePicker`, however the `MainWindow` should block before the dialog is handled, because the `DateTime` object is required to continue.

The following are the constructors for `MainWindow` and its data context:

```
public MainWindow() {
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MyContext();
}

public MyContext() {
   // some code which tries to parse a DateTime date from some data

   if (date == null) {
      MyDatePicker w = new MyDatePicker();
      w.ShowDialog();
      if (w.DialogResult == true)
         myDate = w.DateChosen;
   }

   // do stuff with date here
}
```

Comment: Set data context in window.loaded handler?

Comment: [Form.Shown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AccessDenied I feel so stupid. Thanks.